# rails 3 plugin install declare a specific branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I want to install from a particular branch on a git repo, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plugins:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/user/project.git -r branch_name
```

As gem, in your `gemfile` declare something like:

```
gem "project", :git => "git://github.com/user/project.git", :branch => "branch_name"
```